# TSQL and Modulo

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, math, modulo

How can I do this in T-Sql:

```
SQRT(id) % 1 = 0
```

I can't cast the result of the Sqrt() function because this renders the logic above useless.
Any Ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What logic do you want? `% 1` doesn't make much sense to me.. Are you trying to test if it's a whole number?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
floor(sqrt(id)) = sqrt(id)
```

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 180 
'INT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because I'm not using 2012 but I found it here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634373.aspx

Comment: Ah, that's where I saw it too - seems it's only for something called DAX expressions, though.

Answer (score 1):

To see whether the sqrt is whole, try this: `SQRT(id) * SQRT(id) = id`. This might run into floating point precision issues though. I think this fixes them reliably for all numbers up to a certain threshold:

`CONVERT(INT, SQRT(id)) * CONVERT(INT, SQRT(id)) = id`

After the threshold, the precision will not be enough. You'll see false negatives but never false positives.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast it to a `varchar` and then take the `substring` after the decimal point. More info here: http://dbaspot.com/sqlserver-programming/411976-how-get-numbers-after-decimal-tsql.html